# ios : Creating custom UIControl

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I just want to create a custom uicontrol in ios. 
     In My application I have to dynamically create 4 buttons and one text field in a loop 
[image]

I would like to name that control as QuantityControl. 
    so while dynamically adding that control.
     I want to use like ,
       QuantityControl *mycontrol=[[QuantityControl alloc] init];

Is it possible to merge these 5 control as One control?

pressing -1 will decrement the value in the textfield by 1

pressing -5 will decrement the value in the textfield by 5

pressing +1 will increment the value in the textfield by 1

pressing +5 will increment the value in the textfield by 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you could achieve this by just combining existing controls. Remember that Cocoa Touch philosophy embraces composition of elements much more than it does inheritance.

To me this looks like:

```
[UIStepper]  [UITextField]  [UIStepper]
```

You could create a `UIView` that encloses the three controls and perhaps a controller object that handles the logic/actions from each of the control to update the text in the text field and provide a way of accessing the final value of the control, or implement a delegate to inform interested objects of changes etc.